# react-native-maps fitToSuppliedMarkers does not work on android

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm trying to show all markers on the map. The markers are displayed but I need manually to zoom out to see them all.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!origin || !destination) return;

    mapRef.current.fitToSuppliedMarkers(['origin', 'destination'], {
        edgePadding: { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50 },
        animated: true,
    });
}, [origin, destination]);
```

My map component:
The marker #1: origin
The marker #2: destination

```
<MapView
    style={styles.root}
    ref={mapRef}
    mapType="mutedStandard"
    initialRegion={{
        latitude: origin.location.lat,
        longitude: origin.location.lng,
        latitudeDelta: 0.005,
        longitudeDelta: 0.005,
    }}>

    {...}

    {origin?.location && (
        <Marker
            coordinate={{
                latitude: origin.location.lat,
                longitude: origin.location.lng,
            }}
            title="Origin"
            description={origin.description}
            identifier={'origin'}
        />
    )}

    {destination?.location && (
        <Marker
            coordinate={{
                latitude: destination.location.lat,
                longitude: destination.location.lng,
            }}
            title="Destination"
            description={destination.description}
            identifier={'destination'}
        />
    )}
</MapView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got fixed. Just need an old version of react-native-maps (@0.31.1)